# Spot colors changing to black in PDF and Ai file but not EPS

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, spot-color

In preview the Ai files shows black. If I open the Ai file the colors are displayed correctly but in a PDF they are totally black. Does anyone know what's going on?

[image: Difference between ai file and eps]

Answer (score 1):

**Apple's Preview application can not render spot colors.** In addition to a few other rendering bugs. This has been true for years. Apple doesn't *appear* to really care.

The solution is simple. Stop using Preview to view PDFs if you want PDFs to be rendered correctly. Use **Adobe Reader** or **Adobe Acrobat**.